# Webpack/Vue loader looks for node module in current directory instead of node_modules

Tags: vue.js, webpack, echarts, vue-loader

I've checked multiple related questions but none seems to fit.

I'm using multiple libraries in my web app, importing them inside Vue single file components without too much hassle as follows:

```html
<script>
  import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
  import Sortable from 'sortablejs'

  export default {
    // etc...
  }
</script>
```

And I can use `DateTime` or `Sortable` or any other library in the code without issues.

I'm now trying to integrate **Apache ECharts** and it's giving me troubles.

Not so much due to the library itself, but in this case, for some reason when I `import * as echarts from 'echarts'` as stated in the [official tutorial](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Use%20ECharts%20with%20bundler%20and%20NPM) it returns the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'echarts' in '/whatever/folder/the/current/file/is'
```

"Whatever folder" means `/main/src/components` when importing from the base component, or `/main/src` when trying to import and register globally in the `main.js` file (as indicated in the first method [here](https://programmer.ink/think/how-to-use-echarts-in-vue-projects.html)).

I know I could try the additional `vue-echarts` module but I **really would like to understand why in this case the loader is looking into the current folder and not in `node_modules` as in the other cases**.

---

**NOTES**

- `echarts` is present in the `node_modules` folder together with the other libraries I use without issues
- I've tried also `import echarts from 'echarts'`

** EDIT **

- Also tried to import submodules, such as `import * from 'echarts/core'`
- Also tried to use `const echarts = require('echarts')`
- Having the same issue with Chart.js, but still not with other libraries I was already using...

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried importing from 'echarts/core' or 'echarts/charts' instead of just 'echarts'? The module not found error is indicating in which file the missing module is imported and not where it is imported from, hence the directory it is showing. It will still look in node_modules I believe

Comment: import * as echarts from 'echarts/core';

Comment: exactly the same thing as above: it gives me `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'echarts/core' in '/main/src'`

Comment: Might be an issue with how echarts was installed or something but webpack seems to be working correctly...hard to tell without reproducing

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, and made sure the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` included the libraries. What could create issues with newly installed libraries but not with old ones?